# Building up puppet variable based on conditions

Tags: puppet

So I'm getting adjusted to the immutable variables in puppet, now looking for some advice, or clarification to whether I'm already on the right track.

I have a directory I'd like to sync, but potentially a number of subdirectories thereof. So I'd like to build up an array of one or more paths to pass to a recursive *file* resource. Ideally, I'd have something like this

```
$paths = ['fist/path'] # assume this is provided via class parameter
# this should work, since it's only overriding what was provided from higher scope
if($condition) {
  $paths += 'second/path'
}
# this won't fly, since $paths has already been set once locally
if($another_condition) {
  $paths += 'third/path'
}
```

but I can't do that, right, since the variables are immutable. What I've come up with as a 'best' approach so far is something like this

```
$paths = ['fist/path']
if($condition) {
  $condition_1_path = ['second/path']
} else {
  $condition_1_path = []
}
if($another_condition) {
  $condition_2_path = ['third/path']
} else {
  $condition_2_path = []
}

$paths = concat($paths, $condition_1_path, $condition_2_path)
```

I'm unsure if *concat* will omit an entry from the result if it's provided an empty array for one of its arguments, but waiting to test that once I [figure out how to get stdlib loaded](https://serverfault.com/questions/538470/how-to-load-puppetlabs-stdlib).

Either way, looking at this code, to me, it's plain hideous. Is there a cleaner way to do something like this?

Comment: Wow, it looks like _concat_ will only work on 2 arguments. This is even more limiting, as I actually have more paths I'd like to potentially add in this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is ugly, but I have done it like this.

```
if($condition) {
  $condition_1_path = 'first/path'
} else {
  $condition_1_path = ''
}
if($another_condition) {
  $condition_2_path = 'second/path'
} else {
  $condition_2_path = ''
}

# split into array based on whitespace
$mylistofpaths = split("$condition_1_path $condition_2_path", '\s+')
```

Comment: Similar to my approach but actually better since you can have 'variable arguments' with strings. I'm currently looking at `concat(concat($v1, $v2), $v3)` lol.